# JSON,parse newlines break the structure

Tags: json, parsing

I have a JSON data, which was working till today, it contains some newlines and spaces. Even though I have tried to replace  newlines and  spaces,  it did not  parse it  as JSON.   Can someone help me with it?

Here is the data that breaks, it reads it as a normal string.

```
{"reject_reason":"No","id":"11","address":"xxxx xxx ","telephone":"05555555545","time":"July 24th 2018, 12:16","price":"14.4","type":"Delivery","customer":"1", "name":"xx xxx","postcode":"xxxx","message":"SECOND LEFT ON SALT HILL 

CALL WHEN OUTSIDE ","payment":"Cash Payment","customerId":"153"}
```

First edit : The reason I did not post it as a code  because It was not giving  line breaks. It was better for mobile users, but sorry you must be one of the  people who follow the rules without questioning, like most of the world. anyways

EDITED FOR ANSWER in case someone  needs.  I have  firstly tried JSON.parse and stringify  replaces, somehow it did not work.
Solution - >

```
try{ myData2 = myData2.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
      myData2 = JSON.parse(myData2);
}catch(e){}
```

Comment: What are you actually asking for -- What the valid JSON equivalent is? Because the newline isn't the only problem; you have numerous commas and quotation marks in the wrong places.

Comment: You should fix the part that wrote the JSON not the one that reads that JSON.

Comment: @dashmug like which parts can you be more specific?

Comment: @ObsidianAge  like which parts? I have been using like this for a long time havent seen any problem until this one.

Comment: Literal newlines are not valid in json strings. Whatever is generating that "json" is broken, that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @JeffMercado  I have edited the original question. And the things that  creates  JSON  is  a database query  that fills  ejs  template.  Database is filled  by users ( it is a note from  user) .  And then it is restored in database.  should I  remove new lines when I store it to database?

Comment: @emredeli Fix the part that writes that "JSON" in the database. Because it it not valid JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to replace new lines by '\n' and '\r' and those will need to be escaped to be fully json-valid (Not actually true.. \r\n\ is json valid, but needs to be double escaped to reach your end destination to desplay new lines correctly).

```
\\r\\n
```

Example.

```
{
    "reject_reason": "No",
    "id": "11",
    "address": "xxxx xxx ",
    "telephone": "05555555545",
    "time": "July 24th 2018, 12:16",
    "price": "14.4",
    "type": "Delivery",
    "customer": "1",
    "name": "xx xxx",
    "postcode": "xxxx",
    "message": "SECOND LEFT ON SALT HILL\\r\\n\\r\\nCALL WHEN OUTSIDE ",
    "payment": "Cash Payment",
    "customerId": "153"
}
```

Comment: This fix has to be done *before* that JSON is written to the DB. Otherwise, you are storing invalid JSON in your DB.

Comment: @dashmug True, but the question was how to parse it, not how to write it.

Comment: My comment was my advice for the OP. He has to apply your fix before it is written to the DB. It wasn't me who downvoted your answer.